# Find all elements in a vector of strings that contain a substring

Tags: c++, vector, string-matching

I have a vector containing a lot of strings.

```
v[0] = "Agra"
v[1] = "Amritsar"
v[2] = "Bombay"
v[3] = "Bangalore"
```

Now what I want here is all the strings starting with a particular letter or letters.

For Example: If the input letter is `B` then I should get all the strings starting with `B`.
If input letters are `BO` then all the strings starting with `BO`

Is there any method apart from iterating the vector sequentially?

Comment: Do you know if the elements are stored in sorted order as in the example data, or is that just coincidence?  If they're sorted, then you can do things like (a modified) binary search for the first match, and then scan until the value cannot match any more.  If they aren't sorted, you can't do that; you have to do a complete scan of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

```
std::vector<std::string> v_source = { ... };
std::vector<std::string> v_destination;

std::copy_if(v_source.begin(),
             v_source.end(),
             std::back_inserter(v_destination),
             [](std::string const& s) { return (s.size() > 0 && s[0] == 'B'); });
```

Comment: @R Sahu i think copy_if will also iterate through all the elements of vector sequentially. Is there any other way, I dont have the luxury to use C++ 11

Comment: @Gaurav, that is correct. If the vector is sorted, you can use `std::find_if` to find the first element that begins with `'B'` and the first element after that does not begin with `'B'`. Then, you can all the items between those iterators to the destination vector. If the vector is not sorted, you'll have to iterate over the entire vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structured tree to store the data.

Comment: Why is this not an attempt to answer the question. A trie will be perfectly capable of searching for substrings with a very good performance.